# Selecting small area from larger map to work within using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am trying to create a map in QGIS of a specific section of land in Oklahoma that contains subdivisions.  I have been able to create and view a map of the entire county using shapefiles for the sections, subdivisions, blocks, lots and road centers.

Is there a way to single out the data contained in that one section and work with only that?

Answer (score 2):

If the data in that particular section is characterized by a specific attribute, you can use a definition query to filter out the unneeded sections. Right click your layer in the layer list and choose properties then select Source and click on Query Builder:

[image]

In the query builder, select the field that contains the attribute and fill in the query that corresponds to your data. In the example here, only the points that have the munic_id equal to M1005 will be displayed.

[image]

If no such attribute exists, you can select the data located in that section and copy it to new layers. Another way is to assign an attribute to the data belonging to that section and apply the query filter afterwards.

Comment: It would be great to flesh out this answer with some screenshots